# Change single line character code with Notepad++ and PythonScript

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, notepad++, iso-8859-1

I currently have a bunch of XML files, and unfortunately our script has created one of the fields with a wrong character code.

```
<App_Data App="x" Name="Medium" Value="Forjado e apoiado pela máquina de propaganda, foi o mito do profeta que tinha aparentemente vindo do nada para fazer história. A verdadeira história de sua família não tinha lugar nesta imagem..." />
<App_Data App="x" Name="Short" Value="Forjado e apoiado pela mÃ¡quina de propaganda, foi o mito do profeta que tinha aparentemente vindo do nada para fazer histÃ³ria. A verdadeira histÃ³ria de sua famÃ­lia nÃ£o tinha lugar nesta imagem..." />
```

Some of my files are correct, so I would have to open one by one in order to decide if the script would be used and I don´t believe there would be a need a serious level of automation in a script to verify the need for conversion.

I only came up with the script below, which is actually a patchwork of codes from the web...

```
texto = editor.findText(FINDOPTION.WHOLEWORD | FINDOPTION.MATCHCASE, 0, editor.getLength(), "Short")
pos = editor.gotoPos(texto[0])
ISOLine = editor.lineCopy()
editor.addText(ISOLine.encode('utf8'))
firstLine = editor.getLine(0)
firstLineUnicode = firstLine.decode('latin-1')
editor.replaceWholeLine(firstLineUnicode.encode('latin-1')
Editor.paste()
```

...but it does not work. I don´t seem to be able to select a whole line and associate it with a variable, but since I am a newbie there may be more issues down the road.

The XML files are in ISO-8859-1 character code, but that portion seems to have come from a UTF-8 source, and the characters were only interpreted as ISO-8859-1 rather than converted.

I can fix it manually by copying this whole line, creating a new file in Notepad++ in ISO-8859-1, pasting the line, and then using the menu "Format > Encode in UTF-8" to make it look right. Then I can select it and copy back to the original XML file.

This however is not very practical so I was wondering if there is a better way with a Python script.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. But regarding where you say: "Some of my files are correct, so I would have to open one by one in order to decide if the script would be used", I think it would be safe to just run the script on all of your files. You don't need to check if they need to be fixed or not; a script that solves your problem should not end up actually changing the files that are already correct. (Of course, you should test this first, just to make sure.)

Comment: @Sweater-Baron Thank you, but if I do have some files with the correct character code in that particular line, a script would also change it, thus creating a problem while solving issues for the others.

Comment: Try doing the "Encode in UTF-8" thing in Notepad++ on an already correct line. I suspect it won't change it.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution for this case, using the notepad function to change the character code from the Notepad++ function rather than using python code.

```
notepad.menuCommand(MENUCOMMAND.FORMAT_UTF_8)
texto = editor.findText(FINDOPTION.WHOLEWORD | FINDOPTION.MATCHCASE, 0, editor.getLength(), "Summary_Short")
curPos = editor.gotoPos(texto[0])
curLineNr = editor.lineFromPosition(texto[0])
curLine = editor.getCurLine()
notepad.menuCommand(MENUCOMMAND.FORMAT_ISO_8859_1)
editor.replaceWholeLine(curLineNr, curLine)
```

This code changes character code from the entire XML first, than finds the correct line, copies it, changes character code back to the original code page, and pastes over the previous line.

I thought I could do the same conversion using python code such as below

```
editor.addText(curLine.encode('latin-1'))
editor.replaceWholeLine(curLine.encode('utf8'))
```

But I never got it to perform the exact conversion I wanted.